# Razor Pages .net 6.0 generate Divs on server side

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor

I want the program can generate Divs using tagbuilder or any methods in a for loop on theserver side.
For exmaple. In my demo.cshtml.cs

```
private async Task LoadAsync()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
       {
          var div = new TagBuilder("div");
          div.AddCssClass("template");
          SOMECODE I DONT KNOW, NEED HELP
       }
}
```

and in my cshtml, what code should I add to make those Divs appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a html string:

```
[BindProperty]
        public string htmlString{ get; set; };
private async Task LoadAsync()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
           {
              var div = "<div class=='template'></div>";
              htmlString+=div;
           }
}
```

And then if you want to use it in demo.cshtml,try to use `@Html.Raw(Model.htmlString)`